# Which report version should I give ghc -X to get both these cases to compile?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've got a haskell file:

```
module Temp where

fails_haskell98 :: Monad m => m ()
fails_haskell98 = do
  if True
  then return ()
  else fail "foo"

fails_haskell2010 :: Monad m => m ()
fails_haskell2010 = do
  let exp = do
      x <- return ()
      return ()
  exp
```

Which I can compile with ghc-7.6.3 is I don't specify a particular haskell report:

```
% ghc Temp.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Temp             ( Temp.hs, Temp.o )
```

However, it contains an error according to `-XHaskell98`

```
% ghc Temp.hs -XHaskell98               
[1 of 1] Compiling Temp             ( Temp.hs, Temp.o )

Temp.hs:5:6:
    Unexpected semi-colons in conditional:
        if True; then return (); else fail "foo"
    Perhaps you meant to use -XDoAndIfThenElse?
```

And a different error according to `-XHaskell2010`

```
% ghc Temp.hs -XHaskell2010
[1 of 1] Compiling Temp             ( Temp.hs, Temp.o )

Temp.hs:12:9: parse error on input `<-'
```

Is there a report flag I can pass ghc (`-XHaskellFoo`) to get both to compile as they do without any flag?

---

These are obviously both fixable by editing the source, but I'm looking for an option that doesn't involve that.

Comment: Why would you want _either_ to compile? It's clearly both bad style.

Comment: From looking at [`Distribution.Simple.Program.GHC`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/libraries/Cabal-1.16.0/Distribution-Simple-Program-GHC.html#v:ghcOptLanguage) it looks like the only valid options are `-XHaskell98` and `-XHaskell2010` or neither.

Comment: The second one compiles under 2010 using GHC 7.6.3 if you indent the inner `do` block again, the `x <-` has to be further to the right than `exp`.

Comment: leftaroundabout: I'm writing a cabal wrapper for a package I don't maintain, just to make it easier to install. Until I can convince the maintainers to take changes, I don't want to have to change any of the source files.

Comment: From looking at [the GHC bugs and infelicities list](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/bugs-and-infelicities.html#haskell-standards-divergence) it looks like GHC operates in a nebulous middleground between Haskell98 and Haskell2010 by default (that is, unless told otherwise).